# Бот не видит сообщения группы

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, бот

Бот не видит никакие события в беседе (он является администратором беседы), вот код:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='токен')

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 'айди группы бота')
vk = vk_session.get_api()


for event in longpoll.listen():
    print('1') #проверка на работоспособность
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять чем это вызвано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убедитесь, что в настройках API сообщества выбраны необходимые вам типы событий LongPoll API.
Для этого зайдите в `Параметры сообщества` > `API` > `Long Poll API` > `Типы собитый` и выберите те события, информация о которых должна передаваться LongPoll-слушателям.
Сохраните и проверьте работу своего бота ещё раз.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое. Всё заработало.